# How can we measure the levels of Frustration?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, measurement, abnormal-psychology, sentiment-analysis

Any technique or Matrix or Questionnaires, Qualitative or Quantitative Analysis

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I'm not too clear on this - is "frustration" some sort of personality trait?  Why would it be measured rather than just asking a person how frustrated they feel right now?

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your question. Questions should be backed up by some background to place it in perspective. Further, evidence of prior research efforts can greatly improve the question. This post is basically a one-liner and below this community's standards as such. Please edit the question acccordingly.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour (Mobbs, 2020), frustration is an emotion that can be visualised on the two dimensional grid as shown below.

The atlas paper describes a method for measuring emotions (and behaviours and personality traits) according to the orthogonal dimensions of affiliation and dominance. The neurobiological basis for the two dimensions are described in the paper as are the evolutionary associations with other vertebrates.

The atlas facilitates measuring such emotions using either a scalar or vector approach.

A scalar measure of frustration can be achieved by identifying proximate synonymic emotions, such as: aggravation, anger, annoyance, botheration, chagrin, derailment, discontentment, exasperation, impatience, and irritation.  The proportion of these proximate synonyms that apply would be a scalar measure of frustration.

A vectored approach would be to draw a vector from the origin (or some other point) through the cell in which frustration is located (-1,1) and then extending to the extremity of the atlas.  Many points on the vector would have a specific word descriptive of that point or segment along the vector. Fifteen related emotions are visualised to assist in the specification of the end point of the vector. (let me know if you would like others that better fit your need).

[image: Frustration]

**References**

Mobbs, AED (2020) An atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour. PLOS ONE 15(1): e0227877. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877

Mobbs, AED (2020) An Atlas of Personality, Emotion and Behaviour. figshare. Collection. https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.c.4792323.v1

**Declared interest**

I am the author of the atlas paper.

Comment: I found the following article: Tindall IK and Curtis GJ (2019) Validation of the Measurement of Need Frustration. Front. Psychol. 10:1742. doi: 10.3389/fpsyg.2019.01742.  Also, see similar question and response at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/9080/26113